# Port forwarding without admin credentials

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, port

I have a TP-link router for which I have to forward ports.But I'm behind admin router and I don't have admin router login password.I am trying to forward ports on my router but I do not have admin credentials. So, I have to double forward ports. And my IP is private. So, is there any other way to forward ports?

Comment: If you don't have the admin credentials for the router then it will not be possible.